# PHP Upload and Download Script

Tags: php

First off let me just say, i dont want anyone to post solutions because I get more satisfaction coding myself so I would appreciate guidance and ideas.

So i want to build a site, that lets me upload a file, store it, display a list of all uploaded files, and then download a selected file.

Any help as to how I may do this?

In more detail.

step 1:

user selects a button upload file.

step 1: it shows the window where they can browse through their locally stored files and select one of them.

step 3:

They click upload.

step 4: this gets stored (perhaps in mysql database, dont know much about how to do this).

step 5: The user clicks the button 'browse uploaded files'

step 6: the user is shown a list of all the uploaded files

step 7: the user selects one of the files and clicks download.

I hope this has made it clearer

Also I just would like someone to show me where to start really.

Thankyou

Comment: This is pretty broad. Which part of the process do you want input for? How to store the files, how to build the UI....? You may be better off splitting this into more isolated tasks

Comment: Why don't you get started and then tell us where you have a problem. Do you know how to create a form in HTML? How about adding a file field to the form? Do you know how to access the file data once its sent to the server? Where exactly is your first stumbling block?

Comment: This is a Q&A site, not a discussion board. If you don't want an A, don't post a Q!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so you request some guidance rather then code, that's good because no one is going to create you the source for this type of site anyway without some sort of revenue.

---

*please don't take this as an offence but your obviously lacking the skills to develop a system that can handle this sort of user iterations so the below will seem alien to yourself but for others that may be reading it it could help them more then it will help you.*

---

**Begin**

What i would advise is you break down the site into components, and then look at each component with a little more detail.

I would break the site's object down into the following sections:

- Database

  - Layout
  - Type
- Uploading

  - Security
  - Storage
  - Quotas
  - Methods (API?)
- Downloading

  - Limitations
  - Permissions
  - restrictions
- Users

  - Registration Based
  - User Permissions / Roles
  - Subscriptions

there's a lot more to be added but the idea is to look at each component in detail, if you have to get pen and paper then do so, it will only make things easier.

Ok so lets start with the **Database**, the database would probably be pretty simple, MySQL is usually a good choice these days, but there are alternatives.

For the structure you would need to look at all the other aspecs of the site first to be able to understand what is required of the database.

As for the **Uploading** / **Downloading** I would not rely on Apache for this, Apache spawns a new thread per request and when sending large file with speed limitations on them threads stay active for longer so potentially you could have thousands of download / upload threads and cause your servers to be extremely slow.

I would look at *libev* as a concept, which as been incorporated into [Node](http://nodejs.org/) which does not use threads and utilizes the Disk I/O

**libev** + **node** is an event loop structure that runs in a single thread, you then assign callbacks to a disk read for example, then when the disk has spun up and is ready to send you a chunk of data your callback is called, but during the time you assign the callback and the time the callback was actually called the process has handle hundreds of other callbacks you may have set/

The **users** would need to be placed out within a structure chart, creating a plan of how the users would be organized within your structure would help you then understand revenue avenues.

Firstly you should start with a framework that can help you build quick and scalable applications of which you have a lot of control over, such as Codeigniter, this will help you build up a framework for your site to run around, now you can also use Node.JS For this but for security reasons I would advise you only use [Node](http://nodejs.org/) for the passing of file data to the client.

i think you get the idea :)

Answer (score 0):

you should use move_uploaded_file function to store the uploaded file, check if the file type is ok and size and ...
then save the file name to a database, you can add some tags, description which you can use to show or search !

Answer (score 0):

The question is very general - what specifically are you having a problem achieving? Have you read the PHP manual section on file uploads?

There are a number of things you've not taken into consideration - not least accountability for distribution of malware / licensed content.